# Existence and uniqueness to normal of a tangent plane

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus

I am wondering by which theorem is this book is able to claim existance and uniquness of a unique normal vector $\vec{n}(x)$ which is orthogonal to $T_1,\dots,T_n$. Is there a general linear algebra reason why this can be concluded?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Maybe a dimensional reasoning: if you agree that span($T_1,...,T_n$) lives in $\mathbb R^{n+1}$ and $\{T_1,...,T_n\}$ are independent vectors, then the orthogonal space has to be of dimension $1$, there are two possible normal vectors that generate this orthogonal space, namely $n$ and $-n$, and only one of these vectors satisfy the relationship $n•k>0$.

Answer (score 0):

To begin with, although at first it may seem unhelpful, let's show that our normal vector can't be any nonzero vector in the plane.

Let $\vec{v}$ be an arbitrary vector in our hyperplane, and suppose that $\langle \vec{v}, \vec{T}_k\rangle = 0$ for all $k$. Because the $\vec{T}_k$ vectors form a basis for the hyperplane, we can represent $\vec{v}$ as some sum $\sum_k a_k \vec{T_k}$ for real $a_k.$ Now, consider what happens when we take the inner product of $\vec{v}$ with itself using this representation:

$$\langle \vec{v}, \sum_k a_k \vec{T_k}\rangle = \sum_k a_k \langle \vec{v}, \vec{T_k}\rangle = \sum_k a_k (0) = 0$$

By our vector field axioms we know that if $\vec{v}$ is nonzero then $\langle \vec v, \vec v\rangle > 0,$ so since we got $0$ we must have that $\vec{v}$ is the zero vector. So, if $\vec v$ is in the plane and orthogonal to all of the basis vectors, then it must be the zero vector.

---

Now, consider the linear transformation $A: \mathbb R^{n+1} \to \mathbb R^n,$ defined such that if $\vec{y} = A\vec{x},$ then $\vec{y}_k = \langle\vec{x}, \vec{T}_k\rangle$ for all $k.$

The proof that this is a linear transformation follows directly from the linearity of the inner product:

$$[A(c_1\vec{x}_1+c_2\vec{x}_2)]_k = \langle c_1\vec{x}_1+c_2\vec{x}_2, \vec{T}_k \rangle = c_1 \langle\vec{x}_1, \vec{T}_k\rangle + c_2\langle\vec{x}_2, \vec{T}_k\rangle = c_1[A\vec{x}_1]_k + c_2[A\vec{x}_2]_k$$

This transformation is relevant to us because its null space is the vectors $\vec v$ such that $\langle \vec v, \vec T_k\rangle = 0$ for all $k,$ which is exactly the space of normal vectors we're looking for.

Now consider the set $\vec{y}_k = A\vec T_k.$ Suppose that they were linearly dependent: this would mean that $\sum_k c_k A \vec T_k = \vec0$ for some sequence $c_k$ which are not all zero simultaneously. By linearity, this means that $A (\sum_k c_k T_k) = \vec 0.$ However, note that because $\vec T_k$ is a basis for our hyperplane, this would require there to be some nonzero $\vec v$ in the hyperplane such that $A\vec v = \vec 0,$ which we've proven before to be impossible. Therefore, our set of $\vec y_k$ is linearly independent.

This means that the rank of $A$ is at least $n.$ The codomain of $A$ being $\mathbb R^n$ means that the rank of $A$ is also at most $n,$ so we have that the rank of $A$ is exactly $n.$ So, because the domain of $A$ has dimension $n+1,$ by the rank-nullity theorem we have that the dimension of the null space is $1.$ This means that all vectors normal to the hyperplane will be multiples of one vector, and they'll lie along a line.

---

Given this, if $\vec{n}$ is one such normal vector, then $|a\vec{n}| = 1$ implies that $|a||\vec{n}| = 1 \Rightarrow a = \pm \frac1{|\vec{n}|},$ which gives us two unit vectors, and if $\langle a\vec{n}, \hat k\rangle > 0$ then $\langle -a\vec{n}, \hat k\rangle < 0,$ so at most one of them can be upward.